# Javascript, Jquery problems with variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, variables

I'm having a problem using variables with Jquery, and i just can't figure out what the problem is.
In this instance i am trying to insert a random class to my li. When i tried alerting color i can cleary see that it writes .green or .red. Following that logic i should be able to use the variable to add my class right? But it is not working. What am i doing wrong?

```
(function(){

        $('li').on('click', function(){
            var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
            var colorA = ['.green', '.red'];
            var color = colorA[number];

            $(this).addClass(color);
        });
    })();
```

Comment: Try removing the dot at the class names beginnig.

Answer (score 1):

simply replace `colorA` with this:

```
var colorA = ['green', 'red'];
```

jQuery [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) function accepts a class "name" not a class "selector".

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Dot at the class names beginning ;-)